# OpenCensus distributed tracing propagation using both Flask & requests

Tags: flask, python-requests, distributed-tracing, opencensus

I'm attempting to implement distributed tracing via OpenCensus across different services where each service is using Flask for serving and sends downstream requests using... er..  `requests` to build its reply. The tracing platform is GCP Cloud Trace.

I'm using `FlaskMiddleware`, which traces the initial call correctly, but there's no propagation of span info between the source and target service, even when the middleware has a propagation defined (I've tried a few):

```
#middleware = FlaskMiddleware(app, exporter=exporter, sampler=sampler, excludelist_paths=['healthz', 'metrics'], propagator=google_cloud_format.GoogleCloudFormatPropagator())
middleware = FlaskMiddleware(app, exporter=exporter, sampler=sampler, excludelist_paths=['healthz', 'metrics'], propagator=b3_format.B3FormatPropagator())
#middleware = FlaskMiddleware(app, exporter=exporter, sampler=sampler, excludelist_paths=['healthz', 'metrics'], propagator=trace_context_http_header_format.TraceContextPropagator())
```

I guess the question is, does anyone have an example of setting up tracing that traverses several downstream calls when each service is serving via Flask and making downstream requests via `requests`.

Currently I end up with each service having its own trace with a single span.